# Running script from terminal works, but does not work when invoked from Mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstask, sshfs

I have a script file with the following code:

```
if [ ! -d ~/Remote/username/projects  ] 
then  
        sshfs -C -p 22 user@remotecomputer.com:/home/username ~/Remote/username        
fi
```

and when I run it from the terminal, it works, however when I call the script from Objective-C and try to run it, I get `sh: sshfs: command not found`

Here is the my Objective-C code that's calling the file

```
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
    [task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"/Users/username/connect.sh", nil]];
    [task launch];
```

Comment: What happens if you change `sshfs` with its absolute path? I bet it'll work.

Comment: now, it's not giving me an error, but for some reason, sshfs is not remounting the disk.

Comment: Try to use absolute path for `~/Remote/username/projects`? I bet `if` condition is not met and that's why it's not remounting.

Comment: Seems like it is, I tried taking out the if statement, and it's the same problem. Also, I put an echo statement inside the if statement and it gets printed out.

Comment: I've never called a bash script from obj-c, but I have another idea. Maybe you have to consume `stdout` of the script from obj-c, and because you don't do that, script is blocking until you do?

Comment: If I put print statements at the end of the script, they run though.

Comment: try using `/usr/local/bin/sshfs -o`, or wherever the sshfs command is located. (In terminal, you can find it by: which sshfs) or (locate sshfs).

Comment: ok that works! thanks! do you know what the difference is?

Comment: It's just using the absolute path, and the `-o` means options.